# How do I retrieve values from int array of pointers? (context: passing array in pthread_create())

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a int array which I passed in pthread_create():
Apparently I need to cast (void *) for it to work.

```
 pthread_create(&id1, NULL, sorter, (void *)array1);
```

In the sorter function:

Also can anyone suggest a way to calculate array size?

```
void *sorter(void *param){

   int *arr = (int *)param; //access that array we passed

   for(int i=0;i<array.size;i++){
       printf("\n%d",arr[i]);
   }
   printf("%d",*arr[0]);//throws invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’) error


   pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Here's a link to some useful slides on pthreads:

https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs241/fa2010/ppt/10-pthread-examples.pdf

Comment: For the first issue, just change to `arr[0]` instead of `*arr[0]` (not sure why you think you need a `*` there but not for the earlier access in the loop). As for the second question, you need to pass that directly into the thread function. Wrap the array and size into a struct and pass a pointer to that struct to the thread function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a pointer to a struct containing the size, and a pointer to the array

```c
void *sorter(void *param);

struct sized_array
{
    size_t size;
    int *data;
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    // declare id1 somewhere
    int* arr = (int*)malloc(50);
    struct sized_array array1 = { 50, ar_ };
    pthread_create(&id1, NULL, sorter, (void *)&array1);

    // note this will leak memory, this is just a demonstratory example
}

void *sorter(void *param)
{

   struct sized_array *arr = (struct sized_array *)param; //access that array we passed

   for(int i=0;i<arr->size;i++){
       printf("\n%d",arr->data[i]);
   }
   printf("%d", arr->data[0]); // note i removed the dereference here, as it's the value is an int, not an int*

   pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: ```struct sized_array *arr = (int *)param; //access that array we passed``` Why do we cast to ```(int *)```?

Comment: The incorrect type is just a typo I think. But casting is unnecessary in this case. void pointers can be assigned to any other pointer type.

Comment: Ah yes, typo. Fixed now

Comment: Thanks! How can I pass a pointer to my array? I hav a normal integer array, how do I convert it to int *arr?

Comment: I replaced your malloc line with my int *arr= array1;(array1 is my integer array). However I'm getting addresses and not values when we print it